# AtTask REST API: How to Link a Google Drive Document to an AtTask Project

Tags: api, attask

I am trying to link a Google Drive document to a project using the API.

There doesn't seem to be any documentation on how to do this.  I created a document using the web interface and queried the API to look at the fields -- thinking there would be a clue on how to create a new one.  There doesn't seem to be any information exposed in any of the fields pointing to how to create a new AtTask document from a linked Google Drive object.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at http://developers.attask.com/api-docs/#UploadsandDocuments? Once you upload the file you get a handle id.

The handle can then be used when creating an AtTask Document. To create an AtTask Document you will post to to the following URL:

POST /attask/api/document?updates={
    name: aFileName,
    handle: abc...123, (handle from the file upload)
    docObjCode: PROJ, (or TASK, OPTASK, etc)
    objID: abc...123,
    currentVersion:{version:v1.0,fileName:aFileName}
}

Is the issue that REST POST is not working?